# Are “vicar of bray person” and a “fair weather friend” synonyms?

Tags: synonyms

In my language these expressions are quite similar in meaning and I can't really make a difference between them only by looking them up in a  dictionary or online. Thanks for your help dear natives in advance!

Comment: [crosspost](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/145974/2338)

Answer (score 4):

The two expressions are *similar* but have *different contexts*.

The Vicar of Bray referred to was Simon Aleyn (1540 - 1588)

[Worthies of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vicar_of_Bray), published 1662, has this to say of him :

> The vivacious vicar [of Bray] living under King Henry VIII, King Edward VI, Queen Mary, and Queen Elizabeth, was first a Papist, then a Protestant, then a Papist, then a Protestant again. He had seen some martyrs burnt (two miles off) at Windsor and found this fire too hot for his tender temper.

This vicar, being taxed [attacked] by one for being a turncoat and an inconstant changeling, said, '**Not so, for I always kept my principle, which is this – to live and die the Vicar of Bray'**

The 18th century satirical song, '[The Vicar of Bray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vicar_of_Bray_(song))' is a comment on the politics and religion of the period.

Thus to refer to someone as the Vicar of Bray is a matter of political or religious-political expediency, either with a motive of selfish ambition or a motive of survival in dangerous times.

---

A fair weather friend, according to [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fair-weather-friend), is

> someone who is a good friend when it is easy to be one and who stops being one when you are having problems

It bears the same idea as the Vicar of Bray's self-serving attitude but is more personal, towards the individual.

Someone could behave as a 'Vicar of Bray' in politics or corporate, religious matters and yet be a very good friend on a private, individual level. And the corollary could be the case that someone lets their immediate friends down in troublous times but remains politically loyal to a party.

Comment: Thank you Nigel J, I have no idea where you found these pieces of information, you're unbelievable! Thank you!

Comment: You've introduced me to a new term, but a pretty good one.

Comment: @Casey I am also looking for the quote 'We have principles, sir ! (And if you don't like them; then we have others).' I am not sure if it comes from the same source or not.